# recording multiple video feed with timecode/genlock in sync with motion capture system

Tags: sync

So, I am looking into recording 2 HD video streams, as reference for our mocap studio. The thing is that I don't know much about video gear, and it must be fairly cheap. I have asked Vicon (mocap vendor) and others for a solution, but they end up costing 10k $ or more.

I need to have everything triggered when I launch the mocap recording, so genlock and time code.

1) Am I right that only pro cameras have genlock? No comsumer cameras or similar priced?

3) is there other ways of syncing (LANC?) that is compatible with genlock if needed?

3) What kind of video card would I need?

4) I would need some kind of genlock sync generator or master clock to send the signal to all devices. I am not sure how the vicon ultranet switch (mocap system) handles genlock, other than you can buy a Vicon MX Control switch which sends a signal to all devices connected to it(Ultranet and video cams). Does anyone know another way?

Can anyone help me with this? and am I missing something?`

Thanks in advance,
Seb